# regex in python, replace all vowels in word except #hashtag and @username

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to learn regex in python to replace all vowels in word except #hashtag and @username.
but I only know regex for:

find vowels:
`[aiueoAIUEO]`

find @username and #hashtag:
`([@#][\w_-]+)`

example:

`@username blah blah #blah blah #hashtag @blah blah blah`

become:

`@username blh blh #blah blh #hashtag @blah blh blh`

```
import re

s = "@username blah blah #blah blah #hashtag @blah blah blah"

#([@#][\w_-]+)
print(re.sub(r'[aiueoAIUEO]', '', s))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
import re
s = "@username blah blah #blah blah #hashtag @blah blah blah"
print(re.sub(r'([@#][\w-]+)|[aiueoAIUEO]', r'\1', s))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/14nFIi/1) and the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/aRZ6kB).

With `([@#][\w-]+)|[aiueoAIUEO]`, the hashtag/mention gets captured into Group 1, and in that case, `\1` backreference puts it back into the resulting string, else a vowel is matched and removed.

Comment: omg thanks for the answer! i was thinking about this for 2 hours.